# Rank-Nullity Theorem Proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $V$ and $W$ be linear vector spaces. Let $\theta$ be a linear map from $V$ to $W$. Why is $\dim(V) = \dim(\operatorname{Im}(\theta)) + \dim(\ker(\theta))$? I know that there is an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Im}(\theta)$ and $V/\ker(\theta)$, and that the cosets of $\ker(\theta)$ (members of $V/\ker(\theta))$ partition $V$. How can I deduce the relationship from this?

Comment: I've never seen it before, but this has to be a duplicate. See the [rank nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to make the title make sense (just writing the question with no definition of V etc. doesn't seem to cut it) and still state my question. If you have a better suggestion I'd be glad to hear it. I also was not aware of the rank-nullity theorem. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: You didn't state the question in the question box, that's the problem. As for the title, now you know you can change it to something like *Rank nullity theorem proof*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach would be starting like this:

- Let $v_1, \dots , v_p$ be any basis of $\mathrm{ker}\ \theta$.
- Complete it till you have a basis for $V$: $v_1, \dots , v_p, v_{p+1}, \dots , v_n$.
- Then show that $\theta v_{p+1}, \dots , \theta v_n$ is a basis for $\mathrm{im}\ \theta$.

As a consequence,

$$
\mathrm{dim}\ \mathrm{ker}\ \theta + \mathrm{dim}\ \mathrm{im}\ \theta = p + (n-p) = n = \mathrm{dim}\ V \ .
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{im}{\operatorname{im}} \newcommand{\codim}{\operatorname{codim}}$
\begin{align*}\im(\theta)\cong_K V/\ker(\theta) & \Rightarrow \dim_K(\im(\theta))=\dim_K(V/\ker(\theta))  \\
& \Rightarrow \dim_K(\im(\theta)) = \codim_K(\ker(\theta)) \\
&  \Rightarrow \dim_K(\im(\theta))=\dim_K(V)-\dim_K(\ker(\theta)) \\\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using your idea, you need to show that in general, if $T\oplus S=V$, then $V/S\simeq T$.

*Hint*  Take a basis of $S$, say $\mathscr B$, and extend it to a basis of $V$, $\mathscr B\cup \mathscr B_0$. Show that $\mathscr B'=\{v+S:v\in\mathscr B_0\}$ is a basis of $V/S$.

Thus, when working with finite dimensional spaces, $\dim (V/S)=\dim V-\dim S$. Can you see how to conclude?